# PHP code on Visual Composer Plugin

Tags: plugins, php

I want to add some php and html code in my page but i can't do it using Visual Composer, i can choose the "Raw Html" Box but that doesn't render PHP at all, only HTML.

Do you guys have any idea how can i do it?? Or is there a workaround solution?

Comment: You should not be adding PHP code in text editors. It is extremely unsafe. Create a shortcode

Comment: Will a shortcode make me able to add a file like : (Dummy example)

<h2>Hello</h2>
<?php Echo "another hello"; ?>

Comment: Yes, check the shortcode API. Just remember, shortcodes should return, not echo

Comment: I'll test right now and be back for a feedback

Comment: Test worked, Thanx Man Appreciate it (y)

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 13):

So i found the answer with the help of Pieter Goosen and i would like to share it with you:

A good method will be to create a Shortcode.

To do it, just go to your template Functions.php file and create your function like this example:

```
function shortcode_hello( $atts ){
  $time = ( date('G') < 9 ) ? "good morning" : "good day";
    return "Hello, and " . $time . ', my name is Linda';
}
add_shortcode( 'hello', 'shortcode_hello' );
```

Now all you have to do is to place the `[hello]` shortcode on your page builder (Visual composer here).

Comment: Tell your boss that Visual Composer is the cancer of WordPress. Tell your boss that you've separated content concerns from visual one, and that you're not tied into an abhorrent shortcode nightmare should you ever wish to move away from VC and/or change the layout. [ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230804/visual-composer-vs-advanced-custom-fields?rq=1 ]