# Visual Composer vs. Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) (ACF) for all my webpages. Using ACF I think I can create a super easy and simple backend with all the fields the customer needs.

Now a boss asked me why we aren't using [Visual Composer](https://vc.wpbakery.com/) (VC) and I cant get a serious answer and couldn't find any on the internet. In my opinion ACF gives me all the flexibility and backend customisation I need but I don't know exactly how VC works.

Comment: Visual Composer replace the basic editor of textearea and doesn't replace ACF.

Answer (score 11):

Tell your boss that Visual Composer is the cancer of WordPress. Tell your boss that you've separated *content* concerns from visual ones, and that you're not tied into an abhorrent shortcode nightmare should you ever wish to move away from VC and/or change the layout.

To elaborate, "VC vs ACF" isn't really a question - they are two *completely* different products. You should make that clear to your boss.

One is an end-user product for creating "beautiful" websites "without knowing any code" i.e. you might as well sign up at hosting company XYZ for their "website builder" because you're gonna get the same quality of product at the end of it. Not to mention that you need a degree in engineering to use it - it is *horrific*. I honestly can't imagine a *real* "end-user" actually getting on with it. If I were to build these kinds of sites and then hand them back to the client, I would never sleep. I would be barraged with "how do I do this" & "how do I change X" emails 24/7.

The other, whilst anyone can use in principal, is primarily geared at designers & developers who wish to create beautiful interfaces quickly and easily, dealing with your data & content concerns in the *backend* so that you can create beautiful, accessible, semantic websites on the frontend.

I'll leave it up to you to guess which one's which.

Comment: Agree, 100% with this. We had a template come to us with VC and we ended up hiding the entire thing. It's terrible. ACF gives you clean, clear, control. VC is a nightmare of inflexible templates and frustrations.

Comment: ACF is very structured. You tell it what fields are expected, and then you use those fields in your page template's code. This is especially powerful when creating a layout that will be used by many pages. VC or WP Bakery gives you a super powerful page editor. This is useful for one-off pages when a designer has not already specified a design for that page. When you want to give the client control over the page's design. And for allowing the client to easily create new pages that look nice. I'll often use a combination of both plugins on a website.